# py2neo Neo4j TypeError: <map object at 0x03D25C50> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template
from py2neo import Graph,authenticate

app = Flask(__name__)
authenticate("localhost:7474","neo4j", "neo4j")
graph = Graph("http://localhost:7474/db/data")

def buildNodes(nodeRecord):
    print("............................")
    data = {"id": str(nodeRecord.n._id), "label": next(iter(nodeRecord.n.labels))}
    data.update(nodeRecord.n.properties)
    print(data)
    return {"data": data}

def buildEdges(relationRecord):
    data = {"source": str(relationRecord.r.start_node._id),
            "target": str(relationRecord.r.end_node._id),
            "relationship": relationRecord.r.rel.type}

    return {"data": data}

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print("index")
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/graph')
def get_graph():
    # print(graph.cypher.execute('MATCH (n) RETURN n').columns)
    nodes = map(buildNodes, graph.cypher.execute('MATCH (n) RETURN n'))
    print(nodes)
    edges = map(buildEdges, graph.cypher.execute('MATCH ()-[r]->() RETURN r'))
    print(edges)
    # json_2={"nodes":nodes,"edges":edges}
    # return json.dumps(json_2, cls=UserEncoder)
    elements = {"nodes": nodes, "edges": edges}
    print(dict(elements))
    return jsonify(elements)
    return jsonify(elements)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = False)
```

When I use Python to connect the graph database(neo4j), I have the problem 
`'map object at 0x03D25C50' is not JSON serializable`, but `map object at 0x03D25C50` is the result of method of `map()`. I don't know how to resolve the problem.

Is there anything obvious I'm dong wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure if the `map` object has this implemented, but many objects implement the `__str__` method so that you can get a string representation of the data. Sometimes it's just the class name, but for instance the `dict` object will do this: `>>> str({'b':2, 'c':3})
"{'c': 3, 'b': 2}"`

Comment: thanks a lot，I have changed the code，but the problem shows  below，I‘am looking forward your answer. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer to what the error in your image is saying is that you aren't returning a response from your `except` block. And thus because the `try` is failing, your view isn't returning anything. But that doesn't answer the real question. I haven't used `map` in python. `for` loops and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) typically get the job done pretty well. I'm also not familiar at all with `neo4j`. That being said, I believe the answer is that you're using the `__next__` method. Is there any reason why you're doing that explicitly? According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) this used when iterating over an iterable to get the next set of data. In other words it's implicitly called when you loop over an iterable--with a `for` loop for instance. What may be happening is that if there is only one set of data, when you call `__next__` the first time, you get that first and only data set. But when you call it the second time it doesn't have data to return, so you get a `map object`. This may not be the 100% correct answer, but try removing the `__next__` calls, and see if that helps. Try to encode simply `str(edges)` and `str(nodes)` instead of calling `__next__`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, the `map` built-in returned a list. In Python 3, it returns an iterator instead of a list, which the `json` module can't serialize. If you need a list, and not an iterator, you should use a list comprehension: `[buildNodes(row) for row in graph.cypher.execute(...)]`. You can also force-type it by doing `list(map(...))`, but that's not as clear as a listcomp.

You should be aware that you can't call `__next__` (or, preferably, `next(...)`) on a list, however, as that is an iterator method. You can print a whole list without consuming it, though, so unless you're explicitly trying to lazy load, a list is a better option here anyway.

You can read about some of the difference between lists/other sequence types and iterators in the standard docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) and about the `next` built-in function and why it is preferable to `__next__` [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/#id15).